# how to get music album art cover programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-music-player

I want to get music album covers to display them in imageview of gridview.
and this is my code

```
void loadAudioData() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getContentResolver();
        final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        final String albumId = MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID;
        final String albumName = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM;
        final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST;
        final String albumArt = MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART;
        final String album_id = MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ID;
        final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        String[] projection = {albumId, albumName, artist, albumArt, album_id};
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                long album_idx = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(album_id));
                Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_idx);
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), albumArtUri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("bitmap = null", "bitmap = null");
                }
                if (bitmap == null)
                    songsList.add(new Songs(R.drawable.album_cover, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(albumName)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artist))));
                else
                    songsList.add(new Songs(bitmap, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(albumName)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artist))));
            }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

the problem is that bitmap is always null and else statement always executes although there is cover images for albums and they are shown in other installed apps.
i tried too many solutions but non of them helped to the end

Answer (score 0):

Try getting Bitmap using FileDescriptor. See the updated code:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                long album_idx = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(album_id));
                Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_idx);
                try {
                    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContext().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                    if (pfd != null) {
                        FileDescriptor fd = pfd.fileDescriptor;
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, null,options);
                        pfd.close();
                        fd = null;
                    }
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("bitmap = null", "bitmap = null");
                }
                if (bitmap == null)
                    songsList.add(new Songs(R.drawable.album_cover, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(albumName)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artist))));
                else
                    songsList.add(new Songs(bitmap, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(albumName)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artist))));
            }
```

Comment: Unfortunately same result